# Количество информации

Tags: информация

Имеется робот на клетчатой плоскости. На каждом ходу робот случайным образом с равной вероятностью принимает решение двигаться на одну клетку в одном из четырех направлений (вперед, назад, влево или вправо) и осуществляет принятое решение.

Нужно определить сколько бит информации несет в себе сообщение, что в результате четвертого хода робот оказался на две клетки правее своего первоначального положения.

Мои рассуждения:

Всего имеется 25 различных позиций, где робот может оказаться после 4 равновероятных ходов; имеется одна запрашиваемая позиция -> количество информации равно log(25)=5 бит. Где я ошибаюсь в рассуждениях? заранее спасибо, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны считать не конечные позиции (они не равновероятны), а пути (они как раз равновероятны).

Всего путей 4 в 4-ой степени, т. е. 256. Пути, ведущие в конечную точку, такие: EEEW и различные перестановки (4 шт.), и EENS и различные перестановки (4!/2 = 12 шт.), в сумме 16 путей.

Итого ваша информация говорит, что произошло 16 вариантов из 256 возможных. Логарифм посчитайте сами.